# Symfony 4 Service Dependency Injection - Constructor vs Method

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, constructor

So I've got a Symfony controller, and I'm injecting needed services into my methods via params.

One of the params (`MySqlGroupDAO $groupDAO`) is used by all methods of this controller class.

Currently, I'm passing the 'common' param as my last param in each method like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", methods={"POST"})
 * @IsGranted("EDIT_GROUP", subject="parentGroup")
 */
public function addGroup(Request $request, MySqlGroupDAO $groupDAO)  {
    $group = new Group();
    //code to init group from request

    $groupDAO->addGroup($group);

    return new Response("Adding $groupName");
}
```

Doing it this way allows me to eliminate my `__construct` method.  However, I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.  Since it's common across all methods would it be better to re-add my constructor and do something like this?:

```
private $groupDAO;

public function __construct(
    Config $config,
    ValidatorInterface $validator,
    TranslatorInterface $translator,
    RequestStack $requestStack
) {
    parent::__construct($config, $validator, $translator, $requestStack);
    $this->groupDAO = new MySqlGroupDAO($config);
}


/**
 * @Route("/{id}", methods={"POST"})
 * @IsGranted("EDIT_GROUP", subject="parentGroup")
 */
public function addGroup(Request $request)  {
    $group = new Group();
    //code to init group from request

    $this->groupDAO->addGroup($group);

    return new Response("Adding $groupName");
}
```

In doing so, I'm eliminating about half a dozen params across all my methods (in this particular class).  But I'm adding back in my constructor, which requires me to add a class param, and inject several additional params in my constructor since it extends another class.

Is there an advantage to doing it one way vs the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Both options are perfectly fine. I usually go for the constructor method if I use that service more than once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Reasons to use DI in a controller's route methods:**

- Less susceptible to changes of the `parent::__construct` method. Using DI on the constructor means you have to adapt your code whenever this changes. Also notice that some Symfony bundles may assume that controllers have a particular signature and it might make things more complicated for you if it does not.
- If at least one of the routes does not use the service, by using these fine-grained DIs we avoid instantiating a service when this is not necessary (which can be costly if it has its own DIs that weren't already used somewhere else). This can be mostly offset by using [lazy services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) though.

**Reasons to use DI in the contructor:**

- In services other than controllers (and in methods other than route methods of controllers, if any), you can't use autowiring. If you want to inject your dependencies using a method's argument, you'll have to manually pass that dependency with each call. This means in turn that whichever service calls that method should itself have a DI on the required service. The problem is therefore shifted, but it can't be shifted infinitely that way, and at some point you're going to want to use some autowiring on a parent.

**Alternative to using DI in the constructor:**

You can also use [setter injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection) and configure your service [this way](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/calls.html). This is functionally pretty similar to using DI in the constructor, but it bypasses the major drawback of generating a different signature from the parent and being more work to maintain if the parent constructor changes.

You can also make this easier to use for services you often inject. Make the services that need this DI implement an interface and configure them with [_instanceof](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#auto-configure-with-instanceof). Symfony does that with its [`ContainerAwareInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/ContainerAwareInterface.php) and even has a facilitator in the form of [`ContainerAwareTrait`](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/master/ContainerAwareTrait.php) to declare the setter and the property. In your case, if several services require the `MySqlGroupDAO` service, you could define a `MySqlGroupDAOAwareTrait` and `MySqlGroupDAOAwareInterface`, add a `MySqlGroupDAOAwareInterface` entry in your `services.yaml`'s `_instanceof` section, and use the trait and implement the interface in services that need the DI.

---

Edit Nov. 2021:

This answer is still being read by new people, so I thought I'd complete it with something that was added with Symfony 5.2 (and it requires PHP 8): using PHP attributes for dependency injection.

This allows Setter Injection without touching `services.yaml`, and it allows public property injection. Here's the doc's example for both of these:

```
use Symfony\Contracts\Service\Attribute\Required;

class SomeService
{
    // Example of public property injection
    #[Required]
    public Bar $bar;

    // Example of setter injection without editing services.yaml
    #[Required]
    public function setFoo(Foo $foo): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Notice that the property and the setter method used above need to be public (which might or might not be okay with you).

Read more at https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-php-8-attributes.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  Setter Injection was what I was looking for.  Thanks.